# Добавить водяной знак на фото и занести в БД

Tags: php, watermark

дравствуйте. Поставил перед собой такую задачу. Проверить, нужен ли водяной знак для загружаемой картинки. Если нужен, то добавить на него водяной знак и загрузить в базу. Обычная загрузка картинок в базу реализована. Вот код:

```
if($_FILES['news_img']['name']){
    $newsimgExt = strtolower(preg_replace("#.+\.([a-z]+)$#i", "$1", $_FILES['news_img']['name'])); // расширение картинки
    $newsimgDate = substr("$datetime",0,10);
    $newsimgName = "{$news_id}_{$newsimgDate}.{$newsimgExt}"; // новое имя картинки
    $newsimgTmpName = $_FILES['news_img']['tmp_name']; // временное имя файла
    $newsimgSize = $_FILES['news_img']['size']; // вес файла
    $newsimgType = $_FILES['news_img']['type']; // тип файла
    $newsimgError = $_FILES['news_img']['error']; // 0 - OK, иначе - ошибка
    $error = "";

      if(!in_array($newsimgType, $types)) $error .= "Допустимые расширения - .gif, .jpg, .png <br />";
      if($newsimgSize > SIZE) $error .= "Максимальный вес файла - 1 Мб";
      if($newsimgError) $error .= "Ошибка при загрузке файла. Возможно, файл слишком большой";

      if(!empty($error)) $_SESSION['upload_err'] = "<div class='error'>Ошибка при загрузке картинки новости! <br /> {$error}</div>";

    // если нет ошибок
      if(empty($error)){
          if(move_uploaded_file($newsimgTmpName, "../newsimages/$newsimgName")){
              mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET img_path = '$newsimgName' WHERE id = $news_id") or die(mysql_error());
          }else{
              $_SESSION['upload_err'] .= "<div class='error'>Не удалось переместить загруженную картинку. Проверьте права на папки в каталоге /newsimages/</div>";
          }
      }
}
```

Попробовал решить вот так:

```
if($_FILES['news_img']['name']){
        $newsimgExt = strtolower(preg_replace("#.+\.([a-z]+)$#i", "$1", $_FILES['news_img']['name'])); // расширение картинки
        $newsimgName = "{$id}.{$newsimgExt}"; // новое имя картинки
        $newsimgTmpName = $_FILES['news_img']['tmp_name']; // временное имя файла
        $newsimgSize = $_FILES['news_img']['size']; // вес файла
        $newsimgType = $_FILES['news_img']['type']; // тип файла
        $newsimgError = $_FILES['news_img']['error']; // 0 - OK, иначе - ошибка
        $error = "";
              if(!in_array($newsimgType, $types)) $error .= "Допустимые расширения - .gif, .jpg, .png <br />";
              if($newsimgSize > SIZE) $error .= "Максимальный вес файла - 1 Мб";
              if($newsimgError) $error .= "Ошибка при загрузке файла. Возможно, файл слишком большой";
              if(!empty($error)) $_SESSION['answer'] = "<div class='error'>Ошибка при загрузке картинки товара! <br /> {$error}</div>";
        // если нет ошибок
              if(empty($error)){
                if($_POST['logo']){
                      // Загрузка штампа и фото, для которого применяется водяной знак (называется штамп или печать)
                      $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('./templates/images/stamp.png');
                      $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($newsimgName);
                      // Установка полей для штампа и получение высоты/ширины штампа
                      $marge_right = 10;
                      $marge_bottom = 10;
                      $sx = imagesx($stamp);
                      $sy = imagesy($stamp);
                      // Копирование изображения штампа на фотографию с помощью смещения края
                      // и ширины фотографии для расчета позиционирования штампа.
                      $newsimgName=imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
                      // Вывод и освобождение памяти
                      imagepng($im);
                      imagedestroy($im);
                }
                      if(move_uploaded_file($newsimgTmpName, "../newsimages/$newsimgName")){
                              mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET img_path = '$newsimgName' WHERE id = $id");
                      }else{
                              $_SESSION['answer'] .= "<div class='error'>Не удалось переместить загруженную картинку. Проверьте права на папки в каталоге /newsimages/</div>";
                      }
              }
}
```

Но, естественно ничего не получилось, так как функция imagecreatefromjpeg() не может найти нужную картинку, потому что, она еще не загрузилась в нужный каталог. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте после перемешение

то есть,

1. приняли файл
2. Сохранили в папку `move_uploaded_file($newsimgTmpName, "../newsimages/$newsimgName")`
3. если нужно `watermark` сделали `if($_POST['logo']){...}`

примерно так:

```
if(empty($error)){
   if(move_uploaded_file($newsimgTmpName, "../newsimages/$newsimgName")){

     if($_POST['logo']){


       // Загрузка штампа и фото, для которого применяется водяной знак (называется штамп или печать)
          $stamp = imagecreatefrompng("../newsimages/$newsimgName");
          $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($newsimgName);
          // Установка полей для штампа и получение высоты/ширины штампа
          $marge_right = 10;
          $marge_bottom = 10;
          $sx = imagesx($stamp);
          $sy = imagesy($stamp);
          // Копирование изображения штампа на фотографию с помощью смещения края
          // и ширины фотографии для расчета позиционирования штампа.
          $newsimgName=imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
          // Вывод и освобождение памяти
          imagepng($im);
          imagedestroy($im);
    }

      mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET img_path = '$newsimgName' WHERE id = $id");
   }else{
      $_SESSION['answer'] .= "<div class='error'>Не удалось переместить загруженную картинку. Проверьте права на папки в каталоге /newsimages/</div>";
   }
```

Comment: А как потом эту картинку переместить в папку? То есть заменить то, что в папке.

Comment: да заменить то что получили. получится не в временной папке вы обработку делаете а в реальной.